# Expedite a timeout function

Tags: javascript, timeout

```
var timeout = setTimeout(someFunction,50000);
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

This will prevent the someFunction function from running at all. What I want is while the timeout is running, when user clicks some button, they can immediately finish the countdown and execute the `someFunction`. Is this possible?

Comment: Just run the function when they click the button?

Answer (score 1):

As Qantas 94 Heavy suggested in a comment, what you can do is clear the timeout and then run the function on button press.

```js
var timeout = setTimeout(showMessage, 5000);
document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  showMessage();
};

function showMessage() {
  document.getElementById("output").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", new Date() + "<br/>");
}
```

```html
Message will be displayed in 5 seconds.
<input id="stop" type="button" value="Display Message Now" />
<div id="output" />
```